# How to disable the window's title in a FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-titlebar

In my activity that extends the FragmentActivity class, I can't disable the title using `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`. It gives an ANR.

How can I disable a FragmentActivity's title?

This is the partial code of the activity's start:

```
public class NewOrderActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT: ANSWER:**

Okay, I found out that in an activity that has an ActionBar declared in it, the title is a part of the Action Bar not the windows itself.

so in my code I did this to get rid of the window's ( or better to say, ActionBar's ) title:

```
...
...
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
...
...
```

Comment: Have you tried using a NoTitleBar theme in your manifest?

Comment: @Sam: tried it now, it wont work... hmmm any other suggestion?? BTW thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

you should use:-
`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

Answer (score 1):

Try applying `*.NoActionBar` theme to activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity 
    android:name=".NewOrderActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
</activity>
```

Comment: another ANR. to be exact, I am using an action bar in this activity in tab navigation mode. so setting it to no action bar, gives ANR, logically.

Answer (score 1):

This trick solves your problem :)

```java
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();    
bar.hide();
```

or

```
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```